# How to call Ajax Success function variable into other function

Tags: php, jquery, html

How to call Ajax success function variable into Other function, please have a look over the code.

```
var global_data;

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "login.php",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            global_data =   result;
            tick(global_data);

        }
    });

function tick(global_data) {
        $.toast({

        text: '30 days club',
        icon: '',
        loader: false,        
        loaderBg: '#9EC600',  
        allowToastClose: true,
        showHideTransition: 'fade'
        })
    initMap();
    console.log ("Jerry"+global_data);
    setTimeout(tick, random(20, 24) * 1000);
}
```

Here is the code, please have a look and after making all the changes still getting undefined in the console for function tick(global_data).

Comment: `success: function (result) {
            tick(result);` and later `function tick(global_data) {`

Comment: AJAX calls are asynchronous, so you need to use the callback pattern properly. See the duplicates I marked for guides on how to do that. You should also remove `async: false` as it's incredibly bad practice.

Comment: pass value in function parameter

Comment: @ mplungjan you mean to say i have to use function tick(global_data) inside the success:function(result).

Comment: You have `setTimeout(tick, random(20, 24) * 1000);` - that does not have global data passed. You seem to after all to DO need the global data to exist as a global var. So Nikos was not wrong after all. You now need to remove it from the function call: `success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            global_data =   result;
            tick(); 
        }`
and then have `function tick() { if (global_data) { ...process... } setTimeout(tick, random(20, 24) * 1000); }`

Comment: Thanks  @mplungjan it's working for me.

Comment: Feel free to delete the question